# Branch on boolean statement applied to each element of an iterable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, conventions

Is there a Pythonic way to say "is this true of any element in this iterable"? Or, in other words, is there a cleaner version of this:

```
if [True for x in mylist if my_condition(x)]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> any(x > 4 for x in mylist)
False
>>> any(x % 2 == 0 for x in mylist)
True
```

---

```
if any(my_condition(x) for x in mylist):
    ....
```

NOTE: Using [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead of list comprehension, you don't need to evaluate the all items.